# PHP preg_match_all REGEX find all "file(...)" functions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to parse a string containing the dump of a PHP file, to match all the occurrences of the PHP native function `file()`. I'm using `preg_match_all` with a REGEX that is not fully working as expected.

In fact, because I'm looking to match all the occurrences of the `file()` function, I do not want to match results like `$file()`, `$file` or `is_file()`.

This is the PHP code on which I'm trying to match all the occurrences of `file()`:

```
<?php

$x = file('one.php');
file('two.php');

// 

function foo($path)
{
    return file($path);
}

function inFile()
{
    return "should not be matched";
}file('next_to_brackets.php');

foo('three.php');
file('four.php'); // comment

$file = 'should not be matched';

$_file = 'inFile';
$_file();

file('five.php');
```

The REGEX I'm using is the following:

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9\$_]file\s*\(.*?(\n|$)/i

 [^A-Za-z0-9\$_]  Starts with anyting except for letters, numbers, underscores and dollars.
 file             Continue with "file" word.
 \s*              Capture any space after "file" word.
 \(               After the spaces there should be an opening parenthesis.
 .*?              Capture any list of characters (the arguments).
 (\n|$)           Stop capturing until a new line or the end of haystack is found.
 /i               Used for case-insensitive matches.
```

With this PHP code for testing the result:

```
preg_match_all('/[^A-Za-z0-9\$_]file\s*\(.*?(\n|$)/i', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
/*
//Prints:
Array
(
    [0] =>  file('one.php');

    [1] =>  file($path);

    [2] => }file('next_to_brackets.php');

    [3] => 
file('four.php'); // comment

    [4] => 
file('five.php');
)
*/
```

For some reasons, my REGEX is not returning the second occurrence of `file('two.php');` when this is a valid function, not a variable. It is definitely caused by the fact that it's right below another occurrence of the match (`$x = file('one.php');`).

Any suggestions on how to match exact PHP functions in a string containing PHP code?

Thank you!

Comment: Remove `[^A-Za-z0-9\$_]` and put a word boundary metacharacter `\b`. Your regex could be shorten to `\bfile\s*\(.*`

Comment: What is a "dump of a PHP file"?

Comment: Works for me: `\sfile\s*\([^)]*\)`

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool here. To parse php code use the tokenizer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

Comment: If he wants to do a replacement a tokenizer wouldn't be much of a hand. @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: @arkascha: a "dump" of a PHP file is a string containing the PHP code read from a file. Your regex doesn't work as needed though, as it strips ending parentheses when the argument is a nest function.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte tokenizer is not the best solution for me in this case, as I need to match the whole line. Thanks though.

Comment: @revo the boundary works like a charm! Thank you!!

Comment: @AlessioFirenze: the tokenizer returns the line number for each item.